# Python - Pandas - Using Cross-section in conjunction with str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, contains, multi-index

Is there a way to use **the Cross-section method of pandas**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

df.xs('bar',level=0)
```

**in conjunction with the str.contains method**: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

The objective being selecting data at a particular level, but only based on a level containing a given string.

In this specific situation, it would be something like:

```
df.xs(df.str.contains('ba'),level=0)
```

In this specific situation, it should return **(this is an example, obviously here, doing 'bar' or 'ba' would return the same output)**

```
         0         1         2         3
one -0.148672  1.025935  0.948375 -0.214719
two  0.066008  0.429827  0.621165 -0.534449
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
df = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).str.contains('ba')]
print (df)
                0         1         2         3
bar one -0.556376 -0.295627  0.618673 -0.409434
    two  0.107020 -1.143460 -0.145909  0.017417
baz one  0.117667 -0.301128  0.880918 -1.027282
    two  2.287448  1.528137 -1.528636  0.052728
```

Details:

```
print (df.index.get_level_values(0))
Index(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'], dtype='object')

print (df.index.get_level_values(0).str.contains('ba'))
[ True  True  True  True False False False False]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Will accept answer after the 10 mins laps.Thanks jezrael